# How to assess agreement among measurement models (factor analysis) from multiple studies?

Tags: meta-analysis, factor-analysis, agreement-statistics, psychometrics, systematic-review

For a [meta-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis), I've been collating studies that apply [factor analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis) on [likert-like scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) surveys for a specific [psychometric construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychometrics). The original speculation from source material is that there should be 5 [latent factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable). Some studies agree with the number of factors, and some don't. I noted that one pair of studies had the same number of factors, but the [rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) ([change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis)) were different. Most of the studies report [factor loadings](https://www.researchgate.net/post/what_is_factor_loading).

There are [guides to doing factor analysis](https://ajp.paramedics.org/index.php/ajp/article/view/93/90), but is there a conventional process for assessing the [psychometric validity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6423000/) of a construct given the reported models from the literature?